# Deploying contract with arguments using raw transaction

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I want to deployed to deploy the following contract that has a constructor with the following arguments.

```
contract test{
    constructor(address _recipient, address _user){
      ...
    }
}
```

I want to deploy this using web3's sendrawtransaction

How do I go about making the raw TX to do so? I already have the signing key generated. Just not sure what to put in the "data" field of the TX and where to put in the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (using web3.js v1):

```
let fs = require("fs");
let Web3 = require("web3");
let web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);

async function send(transaction) {
    let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: ACCOUNT_ADDRESS});
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : gas
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}

async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs) {
    let abi = fs.readFileSync(BINARY_DIR + contractName + ".abi").toString();
    let bin = fs.readFileSync(BINARY_DIR + contractName + ".bin").toString();
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    let handle = await send(contract.deploy({data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs}));
    console.log(`${contractName} contract deployed at address ${handle.contractAddress}`);
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}
```

Usage example:

```
let myContract = await deploy("MyContract", [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
...
```